# How can we make a load that has configurable power factor for 230V AC?

Tags: power, inductor, power-factor-correction

We are hoping to create a lab for students at our university that requires them to measure the power factor and correct for it.
We are working with 230V AC and have a maximum power of 300W.
We were hoping to create a device that lets us adjust the power factor, but have run into quite a few problems. Our biggest issue is that we require extremely large inductors or resistors to make a significant effect on the power factor.

We were wondering if anyone had any good alternatives. We currently have a fan hooked up that results in a power factor of 0.6, but we were hoping to create something more compact.

Our current design is below, but does not have the correct inductors:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvrlMa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Is it also a goal to teach the student to work **safely** with high voltages/live wires? If not, why not use a transformer and work with say 15VAC? It will scale down the size of those inductors and resistors.

Comment: Just teach them theory of RLC tuned circuits and resonance - it's 100% exactly the same as studying power factor correction but smaller components are used.